# Converting JSON object to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How can I convert a JSON object into HTML? I am doing a get request that returns a JSON object "_bodyText" as the key and the HTML as a string as it's value. When I do a JSON.parse(response) I get "Unrecognized token '<'""

Here is the code itself:

```
var _handleResponse = function(response){
    console.log(response);
}

var rcscrapper = function() {

fetch('https://community.recurse.com') 
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => _handleResponse(json)) 
.catch(error => console.log('error: ' + error))
;
}


module.exports = rcscrapper;
```

I need to access the div in the HTML that has child elements I need to access. What is the best way to do this?

Here is the JSON as requested:

```
{"_bodyText":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <title>Community</title>\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"/assets/application-b5c484ef7115cdd18ed06ce34dcc41a9.css\" data-turbolinks-track=\"true\" />\n  <script src=\"/assets/application-ae06e8fa30cc49100443fa67eb2e5653.js\" data-turbolinks-track=\"true\"></script>\n  <meta name=\"csrf-param\" content=\"authenticity_token\" />\n<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"7Bb+U9qEhyFBQvHpLWQTV6u6nbTm7yRjZqoh/0zOfEsZ+VHEZ1CacmRp+QOxAuPxZdA3W341Nh/Nasl/SWfckw==\" />\n  <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"/assets/favicon-eea9bfa662ec6b82d29a214be25f4e0e.ico\" />\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no\">\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n<div id=\"app\"></div>\n<script>\n  community.core.init_app(document.getElementById(\"app\"), \"/assets/logo-small-8b4907edfec6650310c9459c8380c285.png\");\n</script>\n\n\n</body>\n</html>\n","type":"default","url":"","status":200,"headers":{"map":{"":[""]}}}
```

I need to access the "app" div as it contains the content I need.

It looks like the json is processing properly -- how do I parse the HTML contained in it?

Comment: We don't know? May you show us the JSON

Comment: @rahul2001: try JSON stringify and then send get and fetch...show us the JSON then only we could see.

Comment: You are JSON parsing the HTML string itself, show more of your code

Comment: Obviously not valid JSON being returned. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab. See what is actually returned. Need to fix the ajax before you worry about inserting in dom. Please show your code

Comment: This is the fetch request:

fetch('https://community.recurse.com')
  .then(response => _handleResponse(response))
  .catch(error => {
         console.log('error: ' + error)
     });

Comment: This JSON parses correctly. What is `response` that you are passing to JSON.parse? Is it exactly the string that you showed you in your question, as verified by eg printing it out in the console? After parsing the JSON, you will have `_bodyText`, but what are you planning to do with it? It is an entire HTML page.

Comment: Do you have control over what is generating the JSON response? If so change that to response, or make a new response, to return what you actually need. Preferably as data without any HTML

Comment: Re-read the `fetch` document. You need to call `repsonse.json()`.

Comment: You need to add to your question (not in the comments) the precise call you are making to retrieve the remote data and how you are processing the result, highlighting the hitherto unknown and important piece of information that you are using `fetch`.

Comment: @torazaburo I have updated the original post. I think I am processing the json properly but not able to access the HTML as it is javascript. Any idea how to traverse the DOM tree? All the contents I want to scrape are in the "app" div.

Comment: I am getting the HTML string properly but the div='app' is empty because it is async and the response occurs before the div is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your JSON is contained in a `response` object under a `data` key, you can do something like this:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(response.data);
document.write(myObject._bodyText);
document.close();
```

Comment: Not following. He doesn't have an "object containing his JSON", he has a string containing the JSON, which he can't **parse** to get the object you show. Once that's sorted out, are you convinced that blasting an entire HTML page with `html` and `head` and all into the `body` of the current document is going to do something useful?

Comment: I am assuming he has some kind of `response` object containing the string.  And as it's called `_bodyText` I think it's safe to assume it's either some text he wants to insert into the document, or a complete `<body>`.  Either way, this site is about indicating a direction, not providing complete solutions.  Crikey - nobody would learn a thing!

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a promise for a `response` object, on which you need to call the `json` method, which itself returns a promise.

```
fetch('community.recurse.com') . 
    then(response => response.json() . 
        then(function(json) { parse_html(json._bodyText); })
    ) .
    catch(error => console.log('error: ' + error))
;
```

Once you have gotten the JSON by calling `response.json()`, get the HTML string from the `_bodyText` property, and call `parse_html` on the HTML string to parse it into a DOM representation, which you can access/query/manipulate using standards DOM APIs:

```
function parse_html(htmlString) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
    var document = htmlDoc.documentElement;
    var myDiv = document.querySelector('div.app');
    // Do something with myDiv
}
```

Comment: When doing this call, I get the following response:

JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string"
RCTJSLog> "error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'"
RCTJSLog> "error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string"

Comment: It works for me. What is the error? What environment are you running in? How are you calling it?

Comment: I am running it in xcode through the react native packager. How are you running it? How do I access the elements of the dom? The fetch method is asynchronously getting the json before loading the contents of the page.

Comment: Can you please post how exactly you are parsing the json and accessing the html dom elements? Thank you.

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing to htmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/html");
?

I am passing (txt, json) is this what you are doing?

Comment: Okay. This is still not working and I'm getting same DOMparser error. Any chance we can screen share and troubleshoot